# Gracenote SDK giving error: User not registered for online use

Tags: c#, sdk, gracenote

I am currently trying to get the sample application working from the GNSDK called "musicid_file_trackid" but it is not working and constantly giving the error "User not registered for online use"...

I am using the C# Wrapper coming with the SDK.

I have registered my application on the Gracenote website and filled in the correct clientId and clientIdTag. I can use the Gracenote Web API without problems using these client details but when I use the GNSDK it gives that user not registered error.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Here are the details of the error message given:

> GNSDK Product Version : 3.07.0.2861   (built 2014-10-28 01:46-0700) A
>   first chance exception of type 'GracenoteSDK.GnException' occurred in
>   gnsdk_csharp.dll GnException : (User not registered for online
>   use)User not registered for online use

Answer (score 0):

Its the version of Visual Studio solution type you have chosen. The UWP does not support that type of exception. I think this is resolved under the VS 2017. Make sure your C# project is also set to the correct platform target. I had to set mine to x64 for mine to ever compile