# Gracenote SDK: User not registered for online use

Tags: gracenote

I just downloaded Gracenote SDK and successfully built samples on Ubuntu but error appeared when I ran those samples:

> ducpa1@101BacTT:~/gnsdk-3.07.7.3701o-20150714/samples/musicid_lookup_album_text$
>   ./sample '34218515' '3B09794059618E8661874A4F544AE0AF' licfile.txt
>   'online'
>
> GNSDK Product Version    : 3.07.7.3701    (built 2015-07-14 12:37-0700)
>
> Info: No stored user - this must be the app's first run.
>
> error from: gnsdk_manager_locale_load()  [on line 438]    0x90800168
>   **User not registered for online use**

Please note that I've already created an App on **developer.gracenote.com** and the above client information should be correct.

I also found a thread created for this issue but no answer was found.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/31382774/gracenote-sdk-giving-error-user-not-registered-for-online-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382774/gracenote-sdk-giving-error-user-not-registered-for-online-use)

Could anyone give me suggestion in this case?

Comment: I got it. My Ubuntu PC had to connect to the internet through a proxy server and the proxy blocked most domains. This might cause the authentication failure. After bypassing the proxy, with free access to the internet, I ran those samples without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've created GnUser for local only but then later trying to use the same user for online.
Please delete the 'user.txt' file and try again so a new user for online can be created.

Comments from the sample code:

```
/* Creating a GnUser is required before performing any queries to Gracenote services,
 * and such APIs in the SDK require a GnUser to be provided. GnUsers can be created
 * 'Online' which means they are created by the Gracenote backend and fully vetted.
 * Or they can be create 'Local Only' which means they are created locally by the
 * SDK but then can only be used locally by the SDK.
 */

/* If the application cannot go online at time of user-regstration it should
 * create a 'local only' user. If connectivity is available, an Online user should
 * be created. An Online user can do both Local and Online queries.
 */
```

Comment: Turns out it's my proxy settings. Anw, thanks for your help :)